# $name token not replaced when creating from branch template

Tags: pipelines, events

Sitecore 9.02 - I have a branch template I've made to create a new page. The template it's based on has a Title field with a standard value set to $name to do the replacement. However, when I create the page with the template, the Title field remains as $name, instead of changing to the name of the item.

I think this has to do with using an item:created event to make modifications to the item, like it's not performing its "base" functionality. Wherever I've got an item that's affected, I'm noticing this behavior.

What's the preferred way to ensure the event doesn't muck up Sitecore's needed functions? Is there a better pipeline/event to use?

Comment: I've seen this before, too, though I've not found a solution to the problem directly. My work-around has been to create a ribbon button that creates the item (branch) and then does the work from the `item:created` after the item is returned.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Any luck with the above issue? I am facing the issue for branch template for specific template. Not sure what was causing the problem

Comment: I don't recall offhand, I might've edited the field manually as part of a custom item:created event. Unfortunately that code's not on my computer at the moment.